# AWS Cloudformation: how to refer multiple security groups in AWS elastic beanstalk configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I am new to AWS Cloudformation world. I am trying to create an elasticbeanstalk configuration template. For it's one of the setting, I need to use two security groups. So, I have given it as following

```
  MyConfigurationTemplate:
  Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
  Properties:
  Properties:
  ApplicationName:  MyApplication
  Description: A default Application
  SolutionStackName: SolutionStack
  OptionSettings:
  ....
  ....
  - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    OptionName: SecurityGroups
    Value:
      !If
        - ConditionIsTrue
        - [!Ref FirstGroup, !ImportValue SecondGroup]
        - !Ref FirstGroup
  ....
  ....
```

I read from AWS docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalinglaunchconfiguration), that SecurityGroups is a list and we can provide comma seprated list. But it is not working for me. AWS throws following error

> Value of property Value must be of type String

I tried giving value of security groups in following ways but none of them worked.

> 1) "!Ref FirstGroup, !ImportValue SecondGroup"
>
> 2)  !Ref FirstGroup, !ImportValue SecondGroup

Any idea how this list of security groups should be provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it myself with some trial and error. As it accepts comma separated list. We need to use **!join** as follows.

```
MyConfigurationTemplate:
Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
Properties:
  ApplicationName:  MyApplication
  Description: A default Application
  SolutionStackName: SolutionStack
  OptionSettings:
  ....
  ....
  - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    OptionName: SecurityGroups
    Value:
    !If
      - ConditionIsTrue
      - !Join [',', [!Ref FirstGroup, !ImportValue SecondGroup]]
      - !Ref FirstGroup
  ....
  ....
```